# Cómo cambiar enlaces internos de un post/amp a enlaces amp

Tags: enlace, amp

Estoy buscando un código que cambie los enlaces internos de una página/amp a enlaces amp, pero solo cuando están en una versión móvil.

He encontrado este código publicado por [Outsource WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960938/if-is-amp-change-internal-links-to-amp-version-wordpress) con el cual es posible cambiar todos los links a 'links amp'. Esto lo hace bien, pero funciona de la misma manera si trabajamos desde una desktop o desde un teléfono móvil. Estos cambios deberían funcionar solo desde un móvil. Por otro lado, observo que los enlaces a páginas externas se cambian a un enlace de amplificador interno en la misma página.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo ajustar este código para que funcione correctamente, sería genial

El código que conseguí es este:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'change_amp_url', 10, 2 );

function change_amp_url( $url, $postobj ) {
static $recursing = false;
if ( $recursing ) {
    return $url;
}

$recursing = true;
if ( function_exists( 'is_amp_endpoint' ) && is_amp_endpoint() ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'post_supports_amp' ) && post_supports_amp( $postobj ) ) {
        $url = amp_get_permalink( $postobj->ID );           
    }
}
$recursing = false;
return $url;
}

/* content link filter */
add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_amp_url_content' );

function change_amp_url_content($content)
{
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $link = $tag->getAttribute('href'); // original url
    $extralink = '';
    if(stristr($link,'#')) {
        $pagelinktemp = explode("#",$link);
        $pagelink = $pagelinktemp[0];
        $extralink = '#'.$pagelinktemp[1];
    } else {
        $pagelink = $link;
    }
    if($pagelink!="") {     
        $postid = url_to_postid($pagelink);
        $postobj = get_post($postid); // getting appropriate post object            
        if($postobj) {          
            $newlink = change_amp_url( $pagelink, $postobj ); //new url
        }
        else {
            $newlink = $link;
        }
    }
    else {
        $newlink = $link;
    }
    if($link != $newlink) // change if only links are different
    {
        $content = str_replace($link, $newlink.$extralink, $content);
    }
}
return $content;
}

/* override canonical link */
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'amp_override_canonical' );

function amp_override_canonical($url) {
if ( substr($url,-4)=="/amp" ) {    
    $url = substr($url,0,-4);
}
return $url;
}
```

Fin del código

Comment: Gracias, Orlando. Ví que corregiste al código

Comment: Orlando, la modificación que hiciste al código modifica correctamente los links internos a links amp pero tiene dos detalles que son los siguientes: (1) El enlace canonical de la entrada amp hace referencia a si misma lo cual es considerado un error por Google "Referenced AMP URL is self-canonical AMP"  y (2) Los links internos que van a otras páginas, les pone un link que apunta a una dirección de la misma página de salida.